# Ansible: How to get disabled but running services?

Tags: ansible, systemd, systemctl

I would like to walk over lots of hosts and get all services that were manually started (systemctl start xxxx) without being enabled first (systemctl enable xxxx) and also vice-versa all services which are disabled (systemctl disable xxxx) but still running (because have not been stopped).

And instead of automatically 'fixing' all of the above found problems I just would like to have them output to my shell.

Something like a for each loop over `systemctl list-unit-files --state=disabled` and running every row through `systemctl is-active` would probably work, but I would need to transfer a small SH script to every host...

Can this be done by Ansible alone? (using RHEL7 Update 7 with kernel 3.10.x)

Edit: This is my playbook so far, but I can not get the loop working:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
     - name: get service facts
       service_facts:
     - name: show report
       when:
        - ansible_facts.services[item + '.service'].state == 'running'
        - ansible_facts.services[item + '.service'].status == 'disabled'
       debug:
         msg: "{{ ansible_facts.services[item + '.service'].status == 'disabled' }}"
       loop:
         ansible_facts.services
```

Comment: Have you tried `ansible.builtin.service_facts`?

Comment: You can also think of having a playbook/role that defines exact state for the services you are interested in.

Comment: @seshadri_c Many customers just want reports.

Comment: Ansible is a powerful configuration management tool. You could perhaps have a script, and run through Ansible if transferring script to hosts is your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question

> *Can this be done by Ansible alone?*

the short answer is: yes, of course. This is what Ansible is made for.

In respect to your headline

> *How to get disabled but running services?*

and the comment

> *Have you tried ansible.builtin.service_facts*

I've prepared a short test which will show the structure of `ansible_facts.services`.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Gather Service Facts
    service_facts:

  - name: Show Service Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.services }}"
```

Which is than, in example for one of the services

```yaml
auditd.service:
  name: auditd.service
  source: systemd
  state: running
  status: enabled
```

So you will need to loop over the result set and looking for `ansible_facts.services[YOURSERVICE].state` and `ansible_facts.services[YOURSERVICE].status`.

In respect to your description

> *... services which are disabled (systemctl disable xxxx) but still running (because have not been stopped) ...*

you may have a look into the answer to [how to declare a variable for `service_facts`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69476972/6771046).

In respect of your comment

> *... how I can do the when condition for all services ...*

and the already mentioned loop over the result, I've added for the test setup

```yaml
- name: Loop over all services and print name
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  when:
    - ansible_facts.services[item].state == 'running'
    - ansible_facts.services[item].status != 'enabled'
  with_items: "{{ ansible_facts.services }}"
```

and found it working.

You may need to adjust the conditionals since that query will report services in status `static` like `dbus` or `systemd-journald` too. Please take also note that a service can also have an `unknow` status. In example

```yaml
splunk.service:
  name: splunk.service
  source: systemd
  state: running
  status: unknown
```

or

```bash
systemctl status splunk
● splunk.service - SYSV: Splunk indexer service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/splunk; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the first draft and the linked question and answer, but still I need to do some kind of IF ${state} -eq 'running' && ${status} -eq 'disabled' before I do a debug msg or debug var. I don't see how I can do the when condition for *all* services. Can you explain that too please?

Comment: @slym45, I've added a `with_item` example. For further usage you may read more about [Ansible Playbook Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html).