# Ansible: How to start stopped services?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I created a playbook that uses `ansible_facts.services` to restart specific services on multiple RHEL servers. The services that get restarted begin with a specific name and may or may not exist on the different hosts where the playbook is ran.

I have this working correctly but I would also like to add a follow up task that checks the services that were restarted in the previous task to make sure they are running. The task would need to only check the services that were restarted then start the service if the status is `stopped`.

Please recommend the best way to do this. Include code if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's sounds odd, but you may try to use handlers (to react on 'changes') and use check_mode for the module to assure the state.

Try to add 'notify' to the restarting task, and `check_mode: true` to the handler. Handler is, basically, the same systemd module, but without ability to change.

... Or, if you want to test your infrastructure, may be you may like testinfra (pytest-testinfra) as a tool to check your infra.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question that you like to make sure that a list of serivces is running.

```yaml
- name: Loop over all services and print name if not running
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  when:
    - ansible_facts.services[item].state != 'running'
  with_items: "{{ ansible_facts.services }}"
```

Based on that example you could start the service if the status is stopped.

**Further Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to get disabled but running services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70376280/6771046)
- [How to list only the running services with `ansible_facts`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70804055/6771046)
- [How to check service exists and is not installed in the server using `service_facts` module in an Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69773111/6771046)

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this. I am now running Ansible service_facts module after restarting the services to check that the status of the restarted services is running. Thanks for the reply.