# Access hosts in play filtered by task

Tags: ansible

I have a task that checks the redis service status on the host list below

```yaml
- hosts: 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3
  tasks:
    - command:
        cmd: service redis-server status
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result
```

After checking I need to access hosts where service does not exist.

And they should be accessible as variable to proceed with them in the next tasks.

Can someone please help?

Comment: could you show the playbook you have tested? because i dont see what you want to do...

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) it is also possible to gather [`service_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_facts_module.html). In example

```yaml
- name: Set facts SERVICE
  set_fact:
    SERVICE: "redis-server.service"

- name: Gathering Service Facts
  service_facts:

- name: Show ansible_facts.services
  debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ ansible_facts.services[SERVICE].status }}"
```

If you like to perform tasks after on a service of which you don't the status, with [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts) you can [check the state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71953222/6771046).

If the service is not installed at that time, the specific variable (key) would not be defined. You would perform [Conditionals based on variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-variables) then

```yaml
when: ansible_facts.services[SERVICE] is defined
when: ansible_facts.services['redis-server.service'] is defined
```

Also it is recommend to use the Ansible [`service`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html) module to perform tasks on the service

```yaml
- name: Start redis-server, if not started
  service:
    name: redis-server
    state: started
```

instead of using the `command` module.

**Further services related Q&A**

- [How to check service exists and is not installed in the server using `service_facts` module in an Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69773111/6771046)
- [Ansible: How to start stopped services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71953222/6771046)
- [Ansible: How to get disabled but running services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70376280/6771046)
- [How to list only the running services with `ansible_facts`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70804055/6771046)

Comment: The answer is great I only add that depending on your ansible_os_family maybe it's better suited to use https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/systemd_module.html

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution that perfectly matches.

```yaml
- name: Check that redis service exists
       systemd:
         name: "redis"
       register: redis_status
       changed_when: redis_status.status.ActiveState == "inactive"

     - set_fact:
        _dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|zip(
                        ansible_play_hosts|map('extract', hostvars, 'redis_status'))) }}"
       run_once: true

     - set_fact:
        _changed: "{{ (_dict|dict2items|json_query('[?value.changed].key'))| join(',') }}"
       run_once: true
```