# How to pass variable from Ansible 'service_facts'?

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-facts

Error when passing variable

```yaml
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    apache_status: "{{ service_status['ansible_facts']['services']['{{ web_pkg }}.service']['state'] }}"
```

Below working fine

```yaml
- name: Fetch Apache Service
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    apache_status: "{{ service_status['ansible_facts']['services']['httpd.service']['state'] }}"
```

Comment: [moustaches don't stack](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names)

Answer (score 1):

Because of your description it is assumed that you are gathering `service_facts`.

So the syntax could be simplified in example

```yaml
- name: Show service state
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_facts.services[web_pkg + '.service'].state }}"
```

Full minimal playbook for testing

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    web_pkg: 'nginx'

  tasks:

  - service_facts:

  - name: Show Service
    debug:
      msg:
        - "{{ ansible_facts.services[web_pkg ~ '.service'].state }}"
        - "{{ ansible_facts.services[web_pkg ~ '.service'].status }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show Service] *****
ok: [test.example.com] =>
  msg:
  - inactive
  - disabled
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to get disabled but running services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70376280/6771046)